# How do I get vb.net to add all links within a particular div class from a webpage?

Tags: html, vb.net

This is what the html rendered code from the webpage looks like

```
<div class="mygallery_entry">
<div class="mygallery_inner">
<a title="img1" class="gallery_image" href="http://image.com/29.html"><img src="/mini/1.jpg" alt="" height="208" width="333" border="0"></a>
</div>
<div class="mygallery_inner">
<a title="img2" class="gallery_image" href="http://image.com/12.html"><img src="/mini/2.jpg" alt="" height="208" width="333" border="0"></a>
</div>
<div class="mygallery_inner">
<a title="img3" class="gallery_image" href="http://image.com/59.html"><img src="/mini/3.jpg" alt="" height="208" width="333" border="0"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

My output goes into a listbox and it should look like this:

```
http://image.com/29.html
http://image.com/12.html
http://image.com/59.html
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to extract information from xml or html. If the html is a valid xml you can use LINQ-to-XML with XPath query or LINQ query syntax get particular information. Otherwise, if the html is not a valid XML and cannot be parsed/loaded to `XDocument`, you should look into [Html Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack). Below is an example using [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) query to get those three image links (*html page need to be downloaded first and stored either as file or as string*).

```
Imports System.Xml.XPath
....
Dim doc = XDocument.Parse(htmlString)
'if you want to load from html file instead of string, use XDocument.Load as follow
'Dim doc = XDocument.Load(pathToHtmlFile)
Dim list = New List(Of String)()
For Each a As XElement In doc.XPathSelectElements("//div[@class='mygallery_inner']/a[@href]")
    list.Add(a.Attribute("href").Value)
Next
```

In the end you'll get all link from html page in `list` variable, ready to be displayed in anyway you want. XPath query expression above
means (read from right to left) :

1. `/a[@href]` : select element `<a>` having `href` attribute and is a direct child of..
2. `//div[@class='mygallery_inner']` : a `<div>` element having `class` attribute value = `mygallery_inner` and is descendant of root element (not necessarily direct child)